# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages?

Tags: templates, yii2, composer-php

I can't extract the file :( what should I do? Thank you in advance.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWgR2.png]

Comment: https://github.com/yiister/yii2-gentelella/issues/9 https://github.com/yiister/yii2-gentelella/issues/12

Comment: Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 0):

```
composer require --prefer-dist yiister/yii2-gentelella "~1.0@dev"
```

you did not post any info on your composer.json, but i'm asuming from the error message that your minimum stability is set to stable, adding `@dev` to the end of the package version tells comoposer to allow dev [stability](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#stability) for this package

Comment: if this doesn't do it for you, please post contents of your `composer.json` file

Comment: Still not working but I tried the, composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.2.1" . and it's not working.